# values changed in bitfields in structure

Tags: c++, c, struct, unsigned, bit-fields

Can anyone explain the output , how the value is stored and calculated?

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct bitfield
{
    unsigned f1:1;
    unsigned f2:2;
    unsigned   :3;
    unsigned f4:4;
    unsigned f5:5;
    unsigned f6:6;
    unsigned f7:1;
    unsigned f8:8;
} bf;

main()
{
    bf.f1 = 1;
    bf.f2 = 0x3;
    bf.f4 = 0xff;
    bf.f5 = -4;
    bf.f6 = 0377;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", bf.f1, bf.f2, bf.f4, bf.f5, bf.f6, bf.f8);
}
```

**Output**: `1 3 15 28 63 0`

Comment: I changed the formatting of the code to make it more readable.

Comment: What needs explaining? This isn't a very useful question. It's like saying "1 + 1 = 2 -- can someone explain?". It all looks obvious, so unless you say what part you don't understand, it's hard to answer this.

Comment: f1 hast 1 bit, it is 1. f2 hast 2 bits an can store 0x3. f4 has 4 bits (range 0-15), storing 0xff sets it to max (15). f5 has 5 bits, 4 = 00100, -4 = 11100 (two's complement), and this is binary equal to 28. f6 has 6 bits, max value = 63. 0377 (oktal) = 255 dec. all 6 bits set to 1, so its value is 63. f8 is never set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned fx:n; // Only use the least significant n bits.

               //                        Binary    Decimal
bf.f1 = 1;     // 1    == [0000 0001]:1   == 1      == 1
bf.f2 = 0x3;   // 0x3  == [0000 0011]:2   == 11     == 3
bf.f4 = 0xff;  // 0xff == [1111 1111]:4   == 1111   == 15
bf.f5 = -4;    // -4   == [0xfffffffc]:5  == 11100  == 28
bf.f6 = 0377;  // 0377 == [1111 1111]:6   == 111111 == 63
```

Answer (score 4):

Very short rundown.

First, `bf` is an uninitialised global variable. This means it will end up in the `.bss` segment, which is typically zero-initialised on startup (although you can pass `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss` to GCC to stop this, not sure about MSVC, and of course it depends on your `crt0`). This explains the value of `f8`, since you haven't written to it.

`f1` is 1. You assign it 1. That one's obvious. Same with `f2` (since hex 3 is dec 3).

`f4` is because the field for f4 is only 4 bits wide. `0xFF` is an 8 bit pattern which is all ones, which is then truncated to 4 bits, and is hence 15 (the highest value that can be represented with 4 bits).

`f5` is due to a signed/unsigned conversion. The 5-bit two's compliment representation of -4 is 11100. If you interpret that value as unsigned (or rather, just a plain binary -> decimal conversion), you get 28.

`f6` is 63 because of an octal conversion. Any C literal number beginning with a zero is treated as octal. Octal 377 is decimal 255 (which is 11111111 in 8-bits), which is then truncated to 6 bits, leaving `111111`. This is 63.

Comment: Global variables are *guaranteed* to be 0-initialised by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 2):

Values are stored in the field you specify. However, since in some cases, e.g `bf.f4 = 0xff;`, the value doesn't fit, it will be losing the upper bits, hence it prints 15 (0x0F). Similarly for -4 stored in `f5` `-4 = 0xFFFFFFFC` as a 32-bit integer, but when stored as an unsigned 5-bit integer, it becomes 0x1C, or 28. The same principle applies to `f6`.

There is also 3 bit "gap" using an unnamed member between `f2` and `f4`.

Internally, the compiler will do this by using AND, SHIFT and OR operations.

Note that we can't know if `f1` is the highest or the lowest bit of the whole value that the fields are stored in. This is something that the compiler implementation will decide on - as long as it's done the same way every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned f1:1;           // 1 bit is allocated. 
bf.f1=1;                 // you are storing 1 works fine.

unsigned f2:2;           // 2 bit is allocated.
bf.f2=0x3;               // 3 == '11' in binary so 2 bits are enough so when you print 3 is printed.

unsigned   :3;

unsigned f4:4;          // 4 bit is allocated.
bf.f4=0xff;             // ff is represented as 1111 1111 in binary, 
// but only 4 bits are allocated so only f which is 1111 
// in binary gets stored in this. when you print using %d, 15 is getting printed.


unsigned f5:5;         // 5 bits are allocated
bf.f5=-4;              // -4 in binary for 5 bits is 11100 but you are printing it as %d so it will print 28. and so on...
```

hope this will help.